# Apply controller to template without a route in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, controller, routes

If I have a template that does not have its own route, how can I apply a controller to it? I have a template called `Cart` that is embedded in another template called `Products`:

```
<template name="Products">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">
        {{> Cart}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't have any route like www.myapp.com/cart or anything. If I use something like:

`Router.route(, {name: 'Cart', controller: 'cartController});`

I will get an error. Can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: A route controller specifies options for the route, not for a template. Can you explain more about what you're trying to accomplish?  Normally you'd just create a cart.js file with your template helpers and event handlers.

Comment: And I assume that ' missing at the end of string is just a missclick while pasting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was probably pointed out to you by the console, you can't have a comma there in JS. It seem your thinking was, just not to pass a route to the `route`. To do that in JS you'd have to do `Router.route(undefined, ...)`. But that's btw..

It seems to me from reading the iron-router guide that you can [simply pass a template to the controller](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#creating-route-controllers). That way they are hooked together too.

I copied the example in the guide and edited to fit your needs:

```
CartController = RouteController.extend({
  template: 'cart',
  action: function () {
    this.render();
  }
});
```